# Access to local storage of active page

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I need to access to local storage of active web-browser tab from script which globally loaded. Is it possible? If yes, could you please provide example?
p.s. code "window.localStorage[key]" gets info from global storage.
Web-browser: Safari, Mac OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as *"Global Storage"*. `localStorage` is shared across tabs that have the same domain open, but that's it.

I'd suggest adding some kind of identifier to your `key`, to get data for the current tab / window:

```
var currentTabId = parseInt(localStorage.tabIds || -1) + 1;
localStorage.tabIds = currentTabId;

localStorage['myKey' + currentTabId] = "Some data";
```